# How to surpress python's start-up information?

Tags: python

When I type "python" and return in shell, the following lines will come out:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24)
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

How to surpress these lines please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way is to call Python as `python -i -c ""`.  This will also disable any start-up scripts, though.  If you have a start-up script, you can also use `python -i ~/.pythonrc.py` (or however that script is named).

Comment: `python -i $PYTHONSTARTUP` will run the default start-up script without showing start-up information.